# Why doesn't this IF statement return the console message?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why this statment does not pass and print my success message.

A is true and B and C are false... what's the problem here?

```
var A = true;
var B = false;
var C = false;

if(A && (B && C === false)){

    console.log('success');

}
```

Comment: It should be `if(A && !B && !C){`

Comment: That's not syntactically valid JS. `=` is for assignment, not `==`.

Comment: @MattBall sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing B as true. The following should work fine:

```
if(A && (B === false && C === false)){

    console.log('success');

}
```

---

However, you can use shorthand like this:

```
if(A && !B && !C){

    console.log('success');

}
```

Comment: Did you mean "Because you're passing B as **false?**"

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate it out:

```
(true && (false && (false === false))
(true && (false && (true))
(true && (false))
(true && false)
(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

`B && C === false` is NOT equivalent to `B === false && C === false`, instead it is equivalent to `B == true && C === false`.

So, your whole statement is equivalent to:
`A == true && B == true && C === false`

Answer (score 0):

because b is false.

you are comparing only c with false

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, B is set to false, but you were checking if it was true.  A good alternative would be:

```
if(A && !(B && C){
    console.log('success');
}
```

This says "Is A true, and is either B or C **not** true?"

If you wanted to set B to true, your if would look like:

```
if (A && B && !C) {
    console.log('success');
}
```